# QT: не понятно куда девается значение xmlReader.readElementText() (QXMLStreamReader)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Доброе!
Есть следющий код:

```
QString tmpres;
qDebug() << "----------";
qDebug() << xmlReader.name();
tmpres=xmlReader.readElementText();
qDebug() << "tmpres:"+tmpres;
qDebug() << "readElementText:"+xmlReader.readElementText();
```

В консоль выводит:

```
"sbss_new_me" 
"tmpres:30" 
"readElementText:"
```

Не понимаю, куда делось значение xmlReader.readElementText(), строчкой выше было равно 30??

Answer (score 1):

> Не понимаю, куда делось значение xmlReader.readElementText(), строчкой
>   выше было равно 30??

Похоже, функция [readElementText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html#readElementText) считала текущий элемент, вернула его, и перешла к следующему. Или уже закончился документ и считывать нечего.

Проверяйте считыватель на [xmlReader.atEnd()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html#atEnd). Еще можно проверять текущий токен через [xmlReader.tokenType()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html#tokenType) или [xmlReader.tokenString()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html#tokenString), чтобы понять, когда парсер закончил.